# How do I queue up request received from blob trigger?

Tags: azure-functions, queuetrigger

I have a function app which triggers when blob is uploaded or updated. But in my requirement, my container might receive thousands of blobs at a time (customer will upload blobs to container in batch). In this case, as I know function app will run in parallel for each blobs in container. But I need to process them in queue.
So, I am thinking to make use of Queue Storage here. Whenever a blob is uploaded let me add that blob name as a queue message to Queue storage via Blob Triggered Function App then I will have a Queue Triggered Function App which will trigger and process the blob in queue.
Correct me if my approach is wrong? Also, I need to know is there any way to add queue message from function app.

Comment: Add the code in your azure function body, or set the output binding in declarative part. Queue Trigger will triggered according to the time that the messages come in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use in your scenario Azure Event Grid **push-pull** event pattern, where the storage account will push the event directly to the storage queue subscriber handler.

This solution didn't require any coding.

Comment: Roman, any reference link would be helpful as I am new to this Azure.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-handlers#queue-storage

Comment: EventGrid is a good solution if you want to process messages in parallel

Comment: All storage account events are *PUSHed* into the storage queue in the real-time manner, but the events can be *PULLed* based on the needs.

Comment: also, have a look at the warning notice: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#polling

Comment: I successfully able to add queue message when a blob is uploaded. But I am getting whole full of data in JSON format, but I need only blob name. I am not getting it. Any help?

Comment: have a look at the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage also you can use the blob input bindings for azure queue trigger function to get the blob body.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct. I did the same in my application When multiple user uploads images on blob, I added blob `name` and `url` on storage Queue. You can create Azure function to process message from the queue but make sure your Azure function `batchSize` is 1

Azure function Storage Queue trigger defatult batch size is 16 and it will process 16 messages in parallel. [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=csharp#host-json)

**Example** API code to create a new entity and upload entity detail in Queue.

```
await this.adRepository.AddEntity(ad);           
        var adDto = this.mapper.Map<AzureSearchServiceDto>(ad);

        //Push data in Queue
        await this.storageService.PushMessageIntoQueue(AppConstraint.ImageVerificationQueue, adDto .ToJson());
```

**Function To verify the image and Create thumbnail images**

```
[FunctionName("ImageVerificationFunction")]
    public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("%ImageVerificationQueue%", Connection = "StorageConnection")]string message, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"ImageVerificationFunction processed: {message}");
        var azureSearchServiceDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AzureSearchServiceDto>(message);
        await this.imageVerificationService.Verify(azureSearchServiceDto);
    }
```

`storageService` is my custom service to send messages in Storage Queue

Comment: Pankaj, any sample for reference?

Comment: I used your approach of reading subject from queue message, i.e., by deserializing the JSON string. Instead of deserializing entire JSON string, I used LINQ to JSON like:

JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(myQueueItem);
var subject = (string)jObject["subject"];

Comment: Above code I have taken from real application. you can create sample code as per your need and put in github and share link you face any challenges.